# Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a Text component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-router

[image]

I am trying to add my `CardsSection` component into my `Card` component however I keep getting this error about a Text Violation but I'm not even using any Text within my `Tournament`, `Card`, or `CardSection` .js files. I don't see why I'm getting this error. Can someone tell me what to do and why?

**Tournament.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { Card, Button, Spinner, CardSection } from "../common";

class Tournaments extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: "Tournaments"
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <Card>
          <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
            <Image
              style={styles.logo}
              source={require("../../Images/ShoeJackCityLogo.png")}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.formContainer} />
        </Card>
        <ScrollView horizontal>
          <Card>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <CardSection>
                <Image
                  style={styles.product}
                  source={require("../../Images/aj_4_toro.png")}
                />
              </CardSection>
              <CardSection>
                <Image
                  style={styles.product}
                  source={require("../../Images/aj_4_toro.png")}
                />
              </CardSection>
              <CardSection>
                <Image
                  style={styles.product}
                  source={require("../../Images/aj_4_toro.png")}
                />
              </CardSection>
            </View>
          </Card>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#F13C20",
    paddingBottom: 20
  },
  logoContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    paddingBottom: 15
  },
  logo: {
    paddingTop: 15,
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  },
  product: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    marginRight: 50
  }
};
export default Tournaments;
```

**CardSection.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CardSection = (props) => (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
    {props.children};
    </View>
  );

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    position: 'relative'
  }
};

export { CardSection };
```

**Card.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 30,
}
};

export { Card };
```

Comment: Does the error say which line it's happening? Also can you show code of your other components?

Comment: Should `CardSection` be a child of a `View`? Not sure what lib you're using for the `Card` component but I would try removing that `View` and applying the styles to the `Card` so that the `CardSection` is a direct child of the `Card`

Comment: I edited the question and now it displays the picture of the error and the card and card-section componenet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a semicolon concatenated right after your children in CardSection component. This semicolon is interpreted as text and since every text must be within a `<Text>` component, the error is thrown.

To fix the issue, simply change

```
const CardSection = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
    {props.children};
  </View>
);
```

to

```
const CardSection = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
    {props.children}
  </View>
);
```

Comment: I made exactly the same mistake.. Thank you so much!

Comment: My linter did it for me. Cost me quite a while to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing all whitespaces (and possibly line endings) from inside your parent  tag.

Facebook says it's not a bug and working as intended(in a related bug report) and that they haven't introduced any changes into .56, but that's not how it actually works and it is working apparently differently from previous versions.

Also Expo has no problem with extra whitespaces there. How you're supposed to intend it now I can't tell you.